# Change UUID format in Django foreign key

Tags: python, django, postgresql, uuid

I have postgresql DB and using UUID as PK in my models.
When I do something like

```
model.rel_model.id
```

it returns me uuid in 32 chars (without '-' separators, as uuid.hex does) - it so because I wrote custom 'to_python' method.
But when i do

```
model.rel_model_id
```

it returns me uuid with '-' separators like str(uuid). But I'd like to redifine it to get it as in the first sample.
I have found [this bug in Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14518) - is this same problem?

Comment: is this the same when you try this: `str(model.rel_model.id)`

Comment: Take a look here [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#example)

Comment: @Mounir yes, it is like `str(model.rel_model.id)` but as model.rel_model.id slower then model.rel_model_id and appears in a lot of different places it would be better to redefine model.rel_model_id way of work.

Comment: @DmitryTabakerov YES, this is the same BUG.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, using Python's property to define how to get or set the id attribute like this:

```
def getid(self):
    return str(self.id)
def setid(self, value):
    self.id = value
id = property(getid, setid)
```

Comment: In the model who use this uuid.